react-native-maps does not load again when it loses focus
The react native maps is not loading in my sign up form, this component is used in the first page, and if i go two pages in, and come back to the first page that has the map, it doesn't load. Is there a way I can make the map reload once it loses focus like in my case? It needs to load as selectedLocation is not null. It loads perfectly when I open the sign up page for the first time
Here's my component
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import MapView, { Polygon, PROVIDER_GOOGLE, Region } from 'react-native-maps';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import Loader from "../Loader";
import { useSupportedRegionCoordinatesQuery } from "../../store/slices/backendApiSlice";

interface LocationPickerProps {
    onLocationSelect?: (location: { latitude: number; longitude: number }) => void;
    selectedLocation?: { latitude: number; longitude: number } | null;
}

const LocationPicker = ({ onLocationSelect, selectedLocation }: LocationPickerProps) => {
    const [currentLocation, setCurrentLocation] = useState<Region | null>(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [isMapReady, setIsMapReady] = useState(false);
    const [polygonCoordinates, setPolygonCoordinates] = useState<Array<{ latitude: number; longitude: number }>>([]);
    const mapRef = useRef<MapView | null>(null);

    const {
        data: supportedRegionCoordinates,
        isLoading: supportedRegionLoading
    } = useSupportedRegionCoordinatesQuery();

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Hi dear i'm loading", selectedLocation);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (supportedRegionCoordinates && !supportedRegionLoading) {
            setPolygonCoordinates(supportedRegionCoordinates);
        }
    }, [supportedRegionCoordinates, supportedRegionLoading]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const requestLocationPermission = async () => {
            try {
                setIsLoading(true);
                const { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
                if (status !== 'granted') {
                    setDefaultLocationOnMap();
                    return;
                }
                fetchLocation();
            } catch (error) {
                setDefaultLocationOnMap();
            } finally {
                setIsLoading(false);
            }
        };

        requestLocationPermission();
    }, []);

    const fetchLocation = async () => {
        try {
            if (selectedLocation) {
                const region: Region = {
                    latitude: selectedLocation.latitude,
                    longitude: selectedLocation.longitude,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.01,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.01,
                };
                setCurrentLocation(region);
            } else {
                const location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
                if (location && location.coords) {
                    const { latitude, longitude } = location.coords;
                    const region: Region = {
                        latitude,
                        longitude,
                        latitudeDelta: 0.01,
                        longitudeDelta: 0.01,
                    };
                    setCurrentLocation(region);
                    if (onLocationSelect) {
                        onLocationSelect({ latitude, longitude });
                    }
                } else {
                    setDefaultLocationOnMap();
                }
            }
        } catch (error) {
            setDefaultLocationOnMap();
        }
    };

    const setDefaultLocationOnMap = () => {
        const defaultLocation: Region = {
            latitude: 36.684224476195006,
            longitude: 2.8521039399702457,
            latitudeDelta: 0.01,
            longitudeDelta: 0.01,
        };
        setCurrentLocation(defaultLocation);
    };

    const handleRegionChangeComplete = (region: Region) => {
        if (onLocationSelect) {
            onLocationSelect({
                latitude: region.latitude,
                longitude: region.longitude
            });
        }
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {currentLocation && (
                <MapView
                    ref={mapRef}
                    // provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                    style={styles.map}
                    initialRegion={currentLocation}
                    onRegionChangeComplete={handleRegionChangeComplete}
                    onMapReady={() => setIsMapReady(true)}
                >
                    {polygonCoordinates?.length > 0 && (
                        <Polygon
                            coordinates={polygonCoordinates}
                            fillColor="rgba(144, 238, 144, 0.3)"
                            strokeColor="rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.8)"
                            strokeWidth={0.2}
                        />
                    )}
                </MapView>
            )}
            {isMapReady && (
                <View style={styles.markerFixed}>
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons name="map-marker" size={48} color="red" />
                </View>
            )}
            {(isLoading || !isMapReady) && (
                <View style={styles.loaderContainer}>
                    <Loader />
                </View>
            )}
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    map: {
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
        flex: 1,
    },
    markerFixed: {
        left: '50%',
        marginLeft: -24,
        marginTop: -48,
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '50%'
    },
    loaderContainer: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)',
    },
});

export default LocationPicker;

